# required: true on text_field_tag does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a text field tag and for some reason I cannot use html5 validations

```
= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], required: true, placeholder: "Search by user"
```

The html output for the field shows required="required" so it's all good there but I can still submit the search form with the emtpy field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use a browser version that supports the 'required' attribute ? check http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: hey if your form has attribute novalidate then also it will not work so check this also.